# Can I get gml:id from GeoServer GetFeature request

Tags: geoserver, wfs, parameters, getfeature

I want to make a call to GeoServer like `http://someurl:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetFeature& --someParameters&...--` and get from GeoServer just items I requested in the parameters.

For example I would like to have only `gml:id` of all features.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You almost can. The parameter to use is PROPERTYNAME

```
http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=topp:states&PROPERTYNAME=STATE_NAME&
```

However, you can see that you are getting also some extra stuff. FIDs are a special case and you can't select them with PROPERTYNAME.

Answer (score 1):

The choice of `gml:id` is perhaps a bad example, because you will always get it with a GetFeature response (when any feature is returned) irrespective of request.

As mentioned by @user30184 GeoServer provides a [propertyName](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html) parameter with which you can use to request only specific properties to be returned, (you can use a DescribeFeatureType request to determine what properties can be requested).

So if you want **only** the feature ID to be returned, one strategy might be to use the propertyName to request no properties, something like:

`http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=topp:states&PROPERTYNAME&`